# Error creating foreign key (check data types)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a relation between two tables. And here is the query for each table and the foreign key creation,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `quotes` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `quote` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `author` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `topic` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `author` (`author`),
  KEY `topic` (`topic`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `authors` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `period` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `photo` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `references` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `author` (`author`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `quotes` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `author` ) REFERENCES `mytestdb`.`authors` (
`id`
) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT ;
```

But it is throwing the following error,

```
Error creating foreign key on author (check data types)
```

I'm not sure what this error about. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: error message is clear: `mytestdb.authors.id` is unsigned int(10), and `mytestdb.quotes.author` is int(11)

Comment: signed versus unsigned. Chg one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The datatypes and signs must be the same

`int` is not the same as `unsigned int`

the display width is irrelevant

---

`author` is a signed int

`id` is an unsigned int

From the [manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must
>   have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be
>   the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For
>   nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation
>   must be the same.

They are of the same size (int). They are not of the same sign.

The display width of 10 and 11 is irrelevant.

### Demo

```
create table referenced
(   id int(11) primary key
);

create table referencing
(   id int primary key,
    author int(10) not null,
    CONSTRAINT fk_blah FOREIGN KEY (author) REFERENCES referenced(id)
);
```

**works no problem**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `quotes` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `quote` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `author` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `topic` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `author` (`author`),
  KEY `topic` (`topic`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `authors` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `period` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `photo` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `references` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `author` (`author`),
  CONSTRAINT fk_blah222 FOREIGN KEY (author) REFERENCES quotes(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**works no problem**

Comment: The author should be the same size as quotes id int size.

Comment: no, they are of the same size. They are not of the same `sign`. Read it slow (the answer)

Comment: there are 3 things at play here that are confusing to people. Only 2 are relevant. The 2 that are relevant are size, and sign. The 3rd (irrelvant) is display width of 10 and 11.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness.

I have found that adding the foreign key as an alteration to the existing table also generates this error.

Using PHPMyAdmin, I had to delete the table, then recreate it WITH the foreign key. After creating the table, I then had to add the foreign key constraint using the table 'relation view' in PHPMyAdmin.

This doesn't shed any light on why the error occurs in the first place, but this does deal with the problem.

Good luck.